# AngularJs how to call prettyprint?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use prettyprint plugin for my angularjs app.

But cannot make it works. I create a simple directive and call method prettyPrint(), but the code is not formatted.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/yAv4f/2/

```
App.directive('test', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).prettyPrint()
    }
};
});
```

Comment: You'got an error in your jsFiddle : Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyPrint'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified your code and i'll update here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/6/

html:

```
<div ng-app="Knob" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <pre class="prettyprint linemus"></pre>
   <pre class="prettyprint linemus">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&lt;html lang="en"&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</pre>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dom = '&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&lt;html lang="en"&gt;&lt;/html&gt;'
})

App.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(prettyPrintOne(scope.dom));
        }
    };
});
```

Basically, you need to use the file [prettify.js](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/prettify.js) to control the execution of the prettify() function, with prettyPrintOne() you can execute it in a specific html text.

And to simplify the use of the directive, like prettify stlyle, i'll suggest restric to 'C' a class and change the the directive name to 'prettyprint'

Answer (score 6):

I've expanded on the previous answers and created a jsfiddle with a working directive that responds in realtime to model changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/cwrgLd0L/27/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="prettifyTest" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>       
        <input type="text" ng-model="organization.message" />
    </div>
    <prettify target="organization"><pre><code class="prettyprint">console.log('{{target.message}}');
            </code>
        </pre>
    </prettify>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('prettifyTest', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.organization = {
        message: 'Hello, world!'
    };
});

App.directive('prettify', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            target: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = element.html();
            var templateFn = $compile(template);
            var update = function(){
                $timeout(function () {
                    var compiled = templateFn(scope).html();
                    var prettified = prettyPrintOne(compiled);
                    element.html(prettified);
                }, 0);
            }
            scope.$watch('target', function () {
                update();
            }, true);
            update();
        }
    };
}]);
```

h/t to @DanielSchaffer (see [Template always compiles with old scope value in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511269/template-always-compiles-with-old-scope-value-in-directive/27513998)).

Comment: Great work, Ken! Surprised you don't have more upvotes here. Was trying to resolve this same issue myself today.

Comment: @Kato - As an FYI, as I recall, I later discovered a few bugs in my implementation that never got fixed in the jsfiddle (can't remember what they were). Just make sure you do your own testing :-).

Comment: One is that the prettyPrintOne() seems to strip the outer `<pre>` tags for some reason. I just added them back in using prettyPrintOne('<pre>' + complied + '</pre>' ); Another is that line numbers seem to be lost. I decided to live with that one for now.

Answer (score 2):

Angular already has this filter built-in for JSON:

```
<pre>
  {{data | json}}
</pre>
```

If you want to make your own directive, you can use the JSON object directly:

```
app.filter('prettyJSON', function () {
    function syntaxHighlight(json) {
      return JSON ? JSON.stringify(json, null, '  ') : 'your browser doesnt support JSON so cant pretty print';
    }
    return syntaxHighlight;
});
```

With markup

```
  <pre>
    {{data | prettyJSON}}
  </pre>
```

Comment: This anwer is irrelevant, he is not asking for json prettyprint, he wants to to use prettyprint for any type of coding it supports.

Comment: GIven that today in AD 2016, 99.99 of the prettyprints on this planet are requested for JSON data, this is actually the most useful answer of the whole page.

Comment: On top of that, it gives the insightful suggestion than you may want to create a small prettyfier filter specific for a given format, rather that build a generic processor to be spread everywhere in your projects hoping it will operate on whatever data is thrown at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make a small addition to the directive by @carlosmantilla

You can achieve the same thing without creating the scope variable. I have added this correction on [github](https://gist.github.com/subudeepak/9645949)

This should work properly I assume.

http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/143/

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "function f1(){int a;}";
})

function replaceText(str)
{
    var str1 = String(str);
    return str1.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>");
}

app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(prettyPrintOne(replaceText(element.html()),'',true));
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately prevents {{values}} from being replaced. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for quite a while and wanted to chime in here, albeit much later than everyone else (for real though, who's still using AngularJS in late 2017? This guy.) My specific use-case was where I have code (xml) being dynamically loaded on the page which needed to be pretty printed over and over again.

This directive will take in your code as an attribute, remove the `prettyprinted` class that's added to the element right after you run `prettyPrint()`. It will watch for changes on the inputted code from the parent's scope and run the code again when changes occur.

Only dependency is that you have Google's code-prettify. I had it self-hosted, hence the `PR.prettyPrint()` (as instructed in the docs as of sept 2017).

The directive fully encapsulates the needed Google code-prettify functionality for dynamic content.

```
angular.module('acrSelect.portal.directives')
  .directive('prettyPrint', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'code': '=',
        },
        template: '<pre ng-class="{prettyprint: code}">{{ code }}</pre>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('code',function(){
                $timeout(function() {
                    //DOM has finished rendering
                    PR.prettyPrint();
                    element.find(".prettyprint").removeClass("prettyprinted");
                });
            });
        }
      }
  }
]);
```

The html in the parent template might look

```
<pretty-print code="selectedCode" ng-show="codeIsSelected"></pretty-print>
```

Hope this helps another poor soul!