# Calling prettyPrint() dynamically in AngularJS ruins binding

Tags: angularjs, google-code-prettify

I'm trying to prettify some text that is generated dynamically.

```
<div ng-app="Knob" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <pre class="prettyprint">{{text}}</pre>
</div>

var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.text = "hello world";
})

App.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              prettyPrint();
        }
    };
});
```

The output:

```
hello worldtext}}
```

Any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/62/

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by a small directive. Find the answer here [AngularJs how to call prettyprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942607/angularjs-how-to-call-prettyprint/22513369#22513369)

I would like to make a small addition to the directive by @carlosmantilla

You can achieve the same thing without creating the scope variable. I have added this correction on github

This should work properly I assume.

http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/143/

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "function f1(){int a;}";
})

function replaceText(str)
{
    var str1 = String(str);
    return str1.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>");
}

app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(prettyPrintOne(replaceText(element.html()),'',true));
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hello.  If you need to link to a resource to provide an answer, please include a summary of the article/site/answer in your post in case the link becomes broken in the future.

Answer (score 1):

this is a late reply and im sure that you have solved the problem. However there may be some other people stumbling upon this thread with the same problem. I solved this using and adapted version of google-code prettify, which can be found here: https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/tree/master/1.3.0-beta.3/docs/components/google-code-prettify-1.0.1
Simply follow the instructions on that page.

Now, prettifyPrint() can be called globally.

```
(function(){
    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint');
    prettyPrint();
})();
```

I placed this at the bottom of my dynamic template

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, what does prettyPrint() should return ?

It seems quite strange that you don't give any arguments to prettyPrint...

By the way, I think an angular filter would be a better fit for your need instead of a directive.

[EDIT]

This one is working "dynamically" using filter :

**html :**

```
<div ng-app="Knob" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <!--<input ng-model="text" type="text"/>-->
    <pre ng-bind-html-unsafe="text|pretty"></pre>
</div>
```

**js :**

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.text = "class Voila {};";
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 0);
});

App.filter('pretty', function(){
    return function(text) {
        return prettyPrintOne(text);
    }
})
```

You can see it at

http://jsfiddle.net/cSXpV/1/

*You can uncomment the input to change directly the text that will be prettyfied*

**Note that this version is for Angular 1.1.1 (the version you choosed in your initial jsfiddle), for Angular 1.2.*, you have to use ng-bind-html and the ngSanitize module**

Last point : now that it is dynamically prettyfied, the setTimeOut and $scope.$apply can be removed (info for readers)

[/EDIT]

Comment: pretty print is part of Google Code Prettify http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: ok, IMHO, your directive is useless, just remove and it works (pretty print code).

Comment: As far as I can see, prettyPrint is aimed to be called in event callback, but link function is not an event callback, so in this context, Google prettyfier just doing some mess...

Comment: It doesn't work - it applies the class, yes, but does not correctly color syntax for real code.

Comment: I used "int function(int i, int j);" as code in text in your jsfiddle and there was some colors (after removing directive). Moreover you're creating a directive with the very same name as a class that is already used by Google prettifier to launch prettifying, probable conflicts there...

Comment: Can you post your fiddle?

Comment: Ok to simulate dynamic loading of text, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VvmP5/1/ ..coloring doesn't work.

Comment: ok, no idea why it's not working, sorry... my guess is that there is a conflict between angularjs and google's code. And as a workaround, I would try another prettyfier not based on class, but implemented as a function which takes html content as argument, then use this function in a filter or a directive (don't name it prettyprint if google js lib is imported)... thus you can control the execution flow because you are explicitely calling prettyfier

Comment: Yes you can use prettyPrintOne(html). But this isn't working either: http://jsfiddle.net/VvmP5/2/

Answer (score 0):

My directive. It s waiting for `$viewContentLoaded` to be sure the template var(`{{}}`) in it have already been computed by angular. should be used in a `<pre>`

```
.directive('prettyprint', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {
      scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        element.html(prettyPrintOne(element.html(),'',true));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using ng-bind-html.

```
<div ng-app="Knob" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <pre class="prettyprint" ng-bind-html="text"></pre>
</div>


app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.html(prettyPrintOne(element.html(),'',true));
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I find out if you delay 300ms to execute the `prettyprint` function, it works well. see below:

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.text = "hello world";
})

App.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              setTimeout(prettyPrint,300);
        }
    };
});
```