# Applying Google-Prettify in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to apply Google Prettify in AngularJS; it is working well for main page but upon Angular route (after ng-view) it is not working. You can have a look at plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H0JJMYiFlwxlKQXOJgP5?p=preview

By the way I am using this pre tag:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-cpp">
struct DLLNode {
    int data; 
    struct DLLNode *next; 
    struct DLLNode 'prey;
};  
</pre>
```

After the ng-view it is unable to perform the Google Prettify but before that it is working.

Comment: Probably because the prettyprint script runs once, and updates the page then the dom elements from your route template are added after. You need to find a way to trigger prettyprint after route load.

Answer (score 1):

Answer can found in a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081950/calling-prettyprint-dynamically-in-angularjs-ruins-binding).

Basically you have to define a new directive:

```
app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(prettyPrintOne(replaceText(element.html()),'',true));
        }
    };
});
```