# How to pretty print html in angularjs to format it like on a text editor

Tags: angularjs, pretty-print

I have xml documents that aren't well formatted so in turn they aren't formatted by prettyXml that I was using so I am thinking to use pretty print Html if it exists, if so how would I go about doing it?

Note here by pretty print I am referring to indented html like you would view in a text editor.

Comment: Duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942607/angularjs-how-to-call-prettyprint

Comment: Thanks @Adam Harrison, I already saw that and it is doing something other than what I am looking for. I updated my question to reflect that.